# Select statement where fields each contain multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have three tables:

vendors
styles
vendor_styles

A vendor can have many styles.  So there can be multiple rows in vendor_styles for a given vendor id.

What I'm trying to do is given a vendor, I want to find all vendors where there is no overlap at all with styles.  So if the vendor I have is a photographer and a videographer I want to find all vendors that are not photographers and not videographers.  What's happening now is, given that scenario, if a vendor is vendor and a photographer and a dj, it will get returned because it has one style that does not exist when comparing it to the first vendor.  But I want to make sure that if any style is the same that it is not returned.

The select statement I ran is:

```
select * 
from vendors, vendor_styles 
where vendors.id = vendor_styles.vendor_id 
  and vendor_styles.style_id not in 
    (select style_id from vendor_styles where vendor_id = <vendor_id>);
```

The problem is that it basically boils down to

```
(23,25) not in (22, 23, 25)
```

Since 22 is not in the former the condition is true.  What I'm trying to get is if any value in the first set of values is in the second set of values, the condition is false.

Comment: Maybe something using INTERSECT or EXCEPT and a count (you're looking for where intersection is zero elements) [EXCEPT and INTERSECT (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should return the correct result:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM
  vendors v
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM vendor_styles vs1 INNER JOIN vendor_styles vs2
         ON vs1.style_id = vs2.style_id
            AND vs1.vendor_id = 1 --- insert vendor id here
    WHERE
      vs2.vendor_id = v.id)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/360cb2/1).